# How to find what types member of what namespaces of what type of what assembly of a dot net framework is using a given dot net type?

Tags: .net

Example, what `member` of what `type` of what `assembly` in a dot net framework is `using` an enum, (example, System.IO.DriveType in mscorlib.dll)?

Note: `using` means such to be found `member` (Function/Sub/Property) having a parameter or returning type being that given type, which is System.IO.DriveType; Or, a structure/record having that given member.  I expect to find a function in dot net library which can return System.IO.DriveType giving a "Drive Letter", or return a Structure/Record/Type/Class which containing that given member (System.IO.DriveType).  I fail.  I would like find the that function by directly just giving system type: System.IO.DriveType.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer: use https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/driveinfo.cs.  In the  search box, input DriveType, it shows two entries: one is the definition of DriveType and other is the using, which is DriveInfo's property DriveType, which is calling an Win API to get the drive type as an integer enum!.